# Missing eclipse plugin when building ADT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, adt

I am trying to build my own ADT according to this tutorial:
[How to build an Android SDK & ADT Eclipse plugin](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt)

When I run the build_server.sh script I get these errors:

```
generateScript:

[eclipse.buildScript] Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied.
[eclipse.buildScript] Bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk: 
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.core_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.ui_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.dsf_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.launch_0.0.0.
[eclipse.buildScript] Bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.tests:
[eclipse.buildScript]   Missing required plug-in org.junit4_4.5.0.
```

I am using eclipse RCP-ganymede 64 ([eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcpplug-developers/ganymedesr2)).

How can I fix it? the 0.0.0 version does not look to me as a valid version.

Comment: Looks like you need to install the CDT (C Development Tools) component of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

1. Go to the eclipse/cdt page [eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)
2. according to your eclipse version (Kepler/Juno/...) copy the link of the repository
3. open eclipse, help->install new software. past the repository link click add (or enter)
4. check the boxes of the CDT packages, install them.
5. restart eclipse after install and its fixed